# Cannot pull or push using PhpStorm, but it works on the command line

Tags: git, github, phpstorm

I cannot push or pull using PhpStorm. I have a GitHub account connected to PhpStorm and the project I'm working on, but every time I try to pull or push, a 'login to GitHub' window pops up. When I then authorize (again), it just says:

> remote: Repository not found. repository 'https://github.com/xxx/yyy.git/' not found

Things I did or checked:

- revoked access on GitHub and re-authenticated etc.
- deleted the GitHub account from PhpStorm and re-added it
- checked the repository URL; that's the right one (works when I paste it in my browser)
- `git pull` or `git push` on the command line work (from PhpStorm's own terminal window)

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to allow access to the organization on GitHub.

Settings -> Applications -> Authorized OAuth Apps -> Jetbrains -> Organization Access